# Position TikZ node relative to bounding box of overall picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, bounding-box

I would like to draw some points in TikZ, and position them relative to the bounding box of the overall picture. Specifically, I would like to give their y-coordinate explicitly, and have their x-coordinate taken from the left-edge of the picture's bounding box. How can I do this?

Here is an example. Each time I invoke `\myCircle` or `\mySquare`, the circle/square is drawn, and a little "notch" is drawn on the left-hand side. (The purpose of the notch is to be a drawing aid, so users can see where shapes are positioned.) The y-coordinate of the notch is taken from the centre of the circle/square. The x-coordinate is currently fixed at `0`, but I would prefer that to be something like `bounding box of overall picture.west`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\myCircle[2]{%
  \fill[red] (#1,#2) circle (5);
  \draw (-2,#2) -- (0,#2);
}
\newcommand\mySquare[2]{%
  \fill[red] (#1-5,#2-5) rectangle (#1+5,#2+5);
  \draw (-2,#2) -- (0,#2);
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm,y=1mm]
    \myCircle{7}{5}
    \mySquare{26}{0}
    \myCircle{8}{20}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One problem is that you won't know the bounding box until the very end of the picture.  So I would store the y values in a list and then iterate over that list at the very end of the picture (using `execute at end picture`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibility is to create labeled local bounding boxes for referencing later for each path.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcount\mycircle
\newcount\mysquare

\newcommand\myCircle[2]{%
\advance\mycircle by 1\relax
\begin{scope}[local bounding box/.expanded=c\the\mycircle]
    \draw[red] (#1,#2) circle (5);
\end{scope}
}
\newcommand\mySquare[2]{%
\advance\mysquare by 1\relax
\begin{scope}[local bounding box/.expanded=s\the\mysquare]
        \draw[red] ({#1-5},{#2-5}) rectangle ({#1+5},{#2+5});
\end{scope}
}

\tikzset{every picture/.style={
    execute at end picture={
        \ifnum\the\mycircle>0\relax%
            \foreach\myc in{1,...,\the\mycircle}{%
                \draw[overlay] (current bounding box.north west |- c\myc) -- ++(-3mm,0);%
            }%
        \fi%
        \ifnum\the\mysquare>0\relax%
            \foreach\myc in{1,...,\the\mysquare}{%
                \draw[overlay] (current bounding box.north west |- s\myc) -- ++(-3mm,0);%
            }%
        \fi%
        \mycircle=0\mysquare=0%
        }
    }
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm,y=1mm]
    \myCircle{0}{5}
    \mySquare{26}{0}
    \myCircle{8}{20}
    \mySquare{10}{-3}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{2cm}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm,y=1mm]
    \myCircle{-1}{5}
    \myCircle{3}{7}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I might have read the question wrong. So the point is not drawing the notches I guess...

Comment: I’d additionally through in a `\pgftransformreset` so that the notches are not affected by any transformation (scaling/rotation).

Comment: @JohnWickerson I thought notches are just indicators but the geometric shapes should have been placed only by referring to their x coordinate. But now I see that it doesn't make sense too. I guess it's me the problem. I need coffee.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a simplified version of percusse's answer, following Andrew's suggestion to keep just a list of y-coordinates. The code is below. I'd just like to point out two "gotchas" that gave me confusing error messages:

- If `A` and `B` are nodes, you can use `A |- B` to calculate the coordinate with `A`'s x-value and `B`'s y-value. You might expect to be able to write the pair `(x,y)` instead of `A` or `B`, but note the following gotcha: The syntax is `(A |- x,y)` not `(A |- (x,y))`.
- Be careful when using `\x` or `\y` as the iterating variable of a `\foreach` loop. In the code below, it would be fine, but in an earlier version I used `let \p1 = (oldBBox.north west)`, instead of the `|-` syntax, to store the top-left point of the bounding box in `\x1,\y1`. This is a problem if the variables `\x` and `\y` are already in use.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\gdef\ys{} 

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\snoc[2]{%
  \ifx#1\@empty
    \xdef#1{#2}
  \else
    \xdef#1{#1,#2}
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\myCircle[2]{%
  \draw[red] (#1,#2) circle (5);
  \snoc\ys{#2}
}
\newcommand\mySquare[2]{%
  \draw[red] ({#1-5},{#2-5}) rectangle ({#1+5},{#2+5});
  \snoc\ys{#2}
}

\tikzset{every picture/.style={
  execute at end picture={
    \coordinate (oldBBox) at (current bounding box.north west);
    \foreach \yvalue in \ys {%
      \draw (oldBBox |- 0,\yvalue) -- ++(-3mm,0);
    }
    \gdef\ys{}    
  }
}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm,y=1mm]
    \myCircle{0}{5}
    \mySquare{26}{0}
    \myCircle{8}{20}
    \mySquare{10}{-3}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{2cm}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm,y=1mm]
    \myCircle{10}{5}
    \myCircle{3}{7}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```